# Eliminating overlaps and gaps between polygons using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, topology, boundaries, gap

I work in ArcMap 10.8 with an Advanced level license.
I work with geological maps. In particular, the scale is 1:500000. I have a lot of line objects (different elements of a relief) that have common boundaries. There are overlaps and gaps between them. With geodatabase topology, there are more than 3000 such gaps. And this is not the saddest thing. There are also maps at a scale of 1:200000, where there are even more such errors.

The lines were not created by me and I work with what was sent.
I was searching for ways to solve this problem on the Internet and to be honest, I still don't know how to speed up the process. Perhaps someone has encountered so many topological errors. Manually correcting one mistake at a time is long and inefficient. Maybe there are other professional software to make it faster besides ArcMap.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this with ArcGIS, including using a topology (human-assisted) and the Integrate command (fully automatic).